# Disabling Hibernate Validation for specific methods

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-data

I want to disable hibernate validations in a specific method. For example conserve validations for normal save and disable them to saveWithoutValidation method. Is it possible to do this with some annotation?

I know it can be disabled in the configuration with the attribute:

```
<Validation-mode> NONE </ validation-mode>
```

I really just use the validations on controllers with @Valid annotation for form errors. To insert into database I do not need.

My valid solution:

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
...
Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "NONE");
factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [Validating Groups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups):

> Groups allow you to restrict the set of constraints applied during
>   validation. This makes for example wizard like validation possible
>   where in each step only a specified subset of constraints get
>   validated. The groups targeted are passed as var-args parameters to
>   validate, `validateProperty` and `validateValue`.